# Access contents of PyBuffer from C

Tags: python, swig, python-c-api, pybuffer

I have created a buffer object in python like so:

```
f = io.open('some_file', 'rb')
byte_stream = buffer(f.read(4096))
```

I'm now passing `byte_stream` as a parameter to a C function, through SWIG. I have a typemap for converting the data which looks like this:

```
%typemap(in) unsigned char * byte_stream {
    PyObject *buf = $input;
    //some code to read the contents of buf
}
```

I have tried a few different things bug can't get to the actual content/value of my byte_stream. How do I convert or access the content of my `byte_stream` using the C API? There are many different methods for converting a C data to a buffer but none that I can find for going the other way around. 
I have tried looking at this object in gcb but neither it, or the values it points to contain my data.

(I'm using buffers because I want to avoid the overhead of converting the data to a string when reading it from the file)
I'm using python 2.6 on Linux.

--
Thanks Pavel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using buffers because I want to
>   avoid the overhead of converting the
>   data to a string when reading it from
>   the file

You are not avoiding anything. The string is already built by the `read()` method. Calling `buffer()` just builds an additional buffer object pointing to that string.

As for getting at the memory pointed to by the buffer object, try `PyObject_AsReadBuffer()`. See also http://docs.python.org/c-api/objbuffer.html.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you use the `read` method on your file object, the data will be converted to a `str` object; calling the `buffer` method does not convert it into a stream of any kind. If you want to avoid the overhead of creating the string object, you could simply pass the file object to your C code and then use it via [its C API](http://docs.python.org/c-api/file.html).